# Whats the fastest way to ignore case when using re in python?

Tags: python, regex

When using re.search or re.match, is it faster to use `.lower()` or `re.IGNORECASE`?

By faster I mean which takes the least time to execute?

Also is one *more pythonic* than the other? - This is *potentially* opinionated, but I would like to know for my own knowledge, the most important thing is which executes faster when the script is run.

I.E

```
mystring = "TeSt"
lowerresults = re.match("^[a-z]{4}$", mystring.lower())
ignoreresults = re.match("^[a-z]{4}$", mystring, re.IGNORECASE)
```

Edit:
The case of the output is not important, speed and matching the regex I have built is all I am concerned about.

Comment: You can't comapre apples to oranges. Check the matched values.

Comment: If `mystring` is *long*, `mystring.lower()` will *take time*, when trying to match just  `4` characters will be fast.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko OK so are you saying IGNORECASE is faster generally, and would be suggested if you do not know the strings length?

Comment: https://ideone.com/jTh2Tb

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew apologies, I understand now. One returns the original string and one doesn't.  I should have specified that I don't actually care about the output's case.

Comment: Its never wise to convert to a specific case just to use regex. Regex wise though, it is always faster to manually specify upper/lower case characters that are in classes as opposed to using the ignore case modifier at all. Example `^[a-zA-Z]{4}$`

Comment: I appreciate that @x15, however I am currently writing a tool that should not be needed, to parse data that is a complete mess. I don't have a choice in the writing, but I do have a choice in how well it runs, which is why I was going for speed. I enquired about best practice for my own knowledge as opposed to this specific task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally the `re.IGNORECASE` is a better solution overall.

Speedwise, `.lower()` has to transform the string, potentially taking up more time. Also, the resulting matches will be lowercase. In case you want to retain the case in the result, this won't work. Also, space wise you will have to store the lowercase string as well.

Comment: Thank you, this answers both my questions.